# Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Estoy tratando de insertar datos pero me marca ese error, me marca en la entidad IsEnabled la cual tengo así

```
public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
```

Se supone se guarda en la base de datos representado como 0=false y 1=true

incluso valide en el .cshtml

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(d => d.IsEnabled)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.IsEnabled, " ", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.IsEnabled, null, new { @class = "red" })
</div>
```

y en el mensaje de error en la web solo me dice

> The value '1' is not valid for IsEnabled.

Y cuando coloco directamente un True o False en el input me arroja la excepcion del titulo.
Así se muestra en la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puse un checkpoinut en donde inserto datos para saber que recibe y 
IsEnabled si recibe true asi que el problema debe ser otro, dejo el codigo del controlador

```
        public ActionResult Nuevo()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Nuevo(ProductViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (DataProductsEntities db = new DataProductsEntities())
                    {
                        var oProduct = new Products();
                            oProduct.Id = model.Id;
                        oProduct.IdType = model.IdType;
                        oProduct.IdColor = model.IdColor;
                        oProduct.IdBrand = model.IdBrand;
                        oProduct.IdProvider = model.IdProvider;
                        oProduct.IdCatalog = model.IdCatalog;
                        oProduct.Title = model.Title;
                        oProduct.Nombre = model.Nombre;
                        oProduct.Description = model.Description;
                        oProduct.PriceDistributor = model.PriceDistributor;
                        oProduct.PriceClient = model.PriceClient;
                        oProduct.PriceMember = model.PriceMember;
                        oProduct.IsEnabled = model.IsEnabled;
                        oProduct.Keywords = model.Keywords;
                        oProduct.DateUpdate = model.DateUpdate;
                        db.Products.Add(oProduct);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return Redirect("~/Products/");
                }
                return View(model);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Este es el ProductViewModel

```
   public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? IdType { get; set; }
        public int? IdColor { get; set; }
        public int? IdBrand { get; set; }
        public int? IdProvider { get; set; }
        public int IdCatalog { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Observations { get; set; }
        public decimal? PriceDistributor { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceClient { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceMember { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
        public string Keywords { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateUpdate { get; set; }
    }
```

Products():

```
namespace Shoes.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Products
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Products()
        {
            this.Comments = new HashSet<Comments>();
            this.DetailProduct = new HashSet<DetailProduct>();
            this.ImagesProduct = new HashSet<ImagesProduct>();
            this.SimilarProduct = new HashSet<SimilarProduct>();
            this.SizeForProduct = new HashSet<SizeForProduct>();
            this.Qualification = new HashSet<Qualification>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdColor { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdBrand { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdProvider { get; set; }
        public int IdCatalog { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Observations { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PriceDistributor { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceClient { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceMember { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
        public string Keywords { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateUpdate { get; set; }

        public virtual CatBrands CatBrands { get; set; }
        public virtual CatCatalogs CatCatalogs { get; set; }
        public virtual CatColors CatColors { get; set; }
        public virtual CatProviders CatProviders { get; set; }
        public virtual CatTypeProduct CatTypeProduct { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Que tipo de dato tienes en la tabla para ese campo

Comment: @MiguelZarate Es bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio, estás asignando un control **TextBox** a una propiedad de Modelo de tipo **Boolean** (`IsEnabled`) que solo puede tener dos valores, o **True** o **False**.

Lo recomendado para estas situaciones es utilizar un **CheckBox**, y así asegurarte de que los valores introducidos siempre serán los correctos (True o False).

Tienes dos opciones para solucionarlo:

**1)** Utilizando el **HtmlHleper** **`@Html.EditorFor()`**, y dejar que el motor de Vistas Razor decida cual es el control mas adecuado para la propiedad:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(d => d.IsEnabled)
    @Html.EditorFor(d => d.IsEnabled, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.IsEnabled, null, new { @class = "red" })
</div>
```

**2)** O directamente utilizar un **`@Html.CheckBoxFor()`**:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(d => d.IsEnabled)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(d => d.IsEnabled, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.IsEnabled, null, new { @class = "red" })
</div>
```

Comment: Con ambos controladores me sigue mandando la misma excepcion

Comment: Listo agregue mas detalles que descubri y agregue el codigo del controlador, en la base de datos IsEnabled is not null

Comment: Definitivamente confirmado, los que más preguntan hacen de C#,  ASP.net MVC son de España :D

Comment: @fredyfx: jaja.. Y eso es bueno o malo?, a que crees que se debe?, estoy de acuerdo contigo ;)

Comment: Es buenísimo :D con ese dato a tener en cuenta, haré webcasts que se ajusten a esa zona horaria. De los motivos que veo: en las universidades les enseñan más sobre .net en comparación a Latam donde reina Java y PHP principalmente

Comment: En la base de datos IsEnables es bit

Comment: Soy de México amigo haha

Comment: *IsEnabled* es bit

Comment: Una pregunta, en que parte del codigo podria poner de que una condicion si es true = 1 y si es false = 0, creo que ese es el problema, seria en el controlador verdad?

Comment: @n00bz: Si en el controlador en la Acción `public ActionResult Nuevo(ProductViewModel model)`. Pero indica antes en la pregunta los Modelos `ProductViewModel` y `Products` creo que ahí está el problema, mas en concreto en la asignación `oProduct.IsEnabled = model.IsEnabled;` Elimina también los comentarios innecesarios para poder seguir ..

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Agregue el ProductViewModel al final

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Listo, agregado tambien, disculpa los contratiempos

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Disculpa donde es mas viable colocar ese fragmento de codigo intente ponerlo donde esta oProduct.IsEnabled = model.IsEnabled; pero no creo que sea lo ideal